# How do you get the Unix timestamp for the end of today in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, unix-timestamp

I want to get the end Unix timestamp of today.

Get start timestamp of today using this but I want end timestamp of today

```
var now = new Date();
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var timestamp = startOfDay / 1000;
```

Comment: var endTimestamp = timestamp + 24 * 60 * 60 - 1;

Comment: Thank u, Karan, it's working

Comment: If "end of day" is 24:00, then `new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0)` gives milliseconds. If you want seconds, divide by 1,000 and truncate the decimal part: `new Date().setHours(24,0,0,0)/1000|0`. If "end of day" is 1 second before midnight, then use `setHours(23,59,59,0)`.

Comment: BTW, start of day is just `new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0)/1000|0`. :-)

Answer (score 1):

`864e5` is the number of milliseconds in a day (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), and `now % 864e5` is the time part of the date in milliseconds :

```js
var now = new Date
var startOfDay = new Date(now - now % 864e5)
var endOfDay   = new Date(now - now % 864e5 + 864e5 - 1)

console.log(now)
console.log(startOfDay)
console.log(endOfDay)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `.valueOf()` method, to get milliseconds timestamp from date, instead of `date / 1000`
2. To get end of the day, just take next day date and reduce for 1 millisecond

```js
var now = new Date();
var startOfDay = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
// take next day date and reduce for one millisecond
var endOfDay = new Date(new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() + 1) - 1);

console.log({
  startOfDay,
  endOfDay,
  startOfDayTimestamp: startOfDay.valueOf(),
  endOfDayTimestamp: endOfDay.valueOf()
})
```

Answer (score 0):

At First, get today timestamp:

```
var now = new Date();
```

Then get the start of tomorrow:

```
var startOfTomorrow = new Date(now.getUTCFullYear(), now.getUTCMonth(), now.getUTCDay() + 1);
```

Now you have end of today:

```
var timestampOfEndOfDay = (startOfTomorrow - 1);
```

See the result:

```
console.log("End of the Day", new Date(timestampOfEndOfDay) );
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.